# Uninstall LaTeX and reinstall from official site

Tags: package-management, uninstall, dpkg, latex

Ubuntu 14.04

Texlive info :

```
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
```

---

Following [this
post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238301/tikz-new-graphing-library-how-to-use)
I'm thinking about completely removing LaTeX and reinstalling from the official
tug site (can't post link, reputation)

The problem that I'm having is that the Official repositories seem to be behind
the official versions, and I wanted to use TikZ 3.0, I currently have version
2.10 installed and seems to be the latest that I can get from the Ubuntu Repo.

What I'm asking is how I would go about removing and reinstalling Tex and
whether there are any risks that I should be aware of in regards to projects
that I have already written.

If I run `dpkg -l | grep texlive` I get these packages (I've cropped the end of
the info off. Here's a link to the output of `dkkg -l | grep tex` [can't post
link, rep], I'm guessing that all of these packages would have to be
reinstalled after upgrading, or can I just do the 'main' one?

```
ii  texlive                                               2013.20140215-1                                     
ii  texlive-base                                          2013.20140215-1                                    
ii  texlive-bibtex-extra                                  2013.20140215-2                                   
ii  texlive-binaries                                      2013.20130729.30972-2build3                      
ii  texlive-extra-utils                                   2013.20140215-2                                 
ii  texlive-font-utils                                    2013.20140215-2                                
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended                             2013.20140215-1                               
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended-doc                         2013.20140215-1                              
ii  texlive-generic-recommended                           2013.20140215-1                             
ii  texlive-lang-english                                  2013.20140215-1                            
ii  texlive-latex-base                                    2013.20140215-1                           
ii  texlive-latex-base-doc                                2013.20140215-1                          
ii  texlive-latex-extra                                   2013.20140215-2                
ii  texlive-latex-extra-doc                               2013.20140215-2                         
ii  texlive-latex-recommended                             2013.20140215-1                       
ii  texlive-latex-recommended-doc                         2013.20140215-1                      
ii  texlive-luatex                                        2013.20140215-1                     
ii  texlive-pictures                                      2013.20140215-1                    
ii  texlive-pictures-doc                                  2013.20140215-1                   
ii  texlive-pstricks                                      2013.20140215-2                  
ii  texlive-pstricks-doc                                  2013.20140215-2
```

it seems that the best approach

```
apt-get remove --purge packagenamek
```

### I'm not sure what the best approach is here though, should I delete everything tex and then reinstall everything, or are there select parts that I should remove? I'm not sure if having some parts handled by ubuntu repos and others from Tan site is a problem or not.

edit - I have had to remove some of the links that I originally had because I don't have enough rep, I'll add them in a comment.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of is `sudo apt-get purge texlive*`. Don't know how safe that is.

After you purge everything. Reinstall from the other site. I am a big fan of sledgehammer solutions in favor of elegant surgery for desktop problems.

Comment: "Don't know how safe that is" -> Yeah, that's kind of the reason for this post :) thanks though